# How to detect if Edit Mode is enabled on the server side in DNN 9?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

How can I detect if DNN is in Edit Mode in the Back-End code?

I looked at this link, but it seems to deal with DNN7 on the Client-Side: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/dnn7-detect-page-edit-mode-in-js

For example:

```
if(DotNetNuke.EditMode == true){
// Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PortalModuleBase has an [**IsEditable**](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/584b0f54bd6b6d237594dd9f96053f14db0b1a53/DNN%20Platform/Library/Entities/Modules/PortalModuleBase.cs#L121) property that is true when in Edit Mode.

```
if(IsEditable){
 // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Just in case someone needs it: in theme it's `DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.IsEditMode()`.